# Working with Javascript elements

Tags: javascript

I have some google map markers that sit on a map.  They are controlled by the rout-markers id.  When I do this command:

```
document.getElementById('rout_markers').style.display = 'none';
```

I am able to make all existing markers disappear from the map, which is what I want.  But if new markers are added, I am not able to add them to the rout_markers element by doing this:

```
document.getElementById('rout_markers').value = str;
```

I mean, the markers do appear on the map, just not in the rout_markers id and I can't pass them to the request when I need to.  Is there some way I can get the newly-created markers to get attached to the rout_markers id again?

Is this a generally accepted method of doing things in JS still?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You'll need to post your HTML, I think, because this doesn't make much sense. One thing to note: "id" values really must be **unique** on a page - if you re-use an "id" for more than one element, your page is invalid.  The "class" attribute is what you should use to give elements a "type" or "category" (or, I guess, a "class" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should collect all markers in an object with known keys then find the marker then do what you want to do.

I think, you should have

- **markers** Object that holds all markers in the map
- **addMarkerToMap** Function that adds new marker to map
- **getMarker** Function that gets a marker

and the codes should be like this

```
var markers = {}
```

```
var addMarkerToMap = function(id) {
    var marker = ... // create a new marker and set given id argument as marker id and append marker to map
    markers[id] = marker; // this will inject the created marker to markers Object
}
```

```
var getMarker = function(id) {
    return markers[id];
}
```